# Can't replace text in variable with strreplace

Tags: php, string, variables, replace, text-processing

I have a variable that I echo, like this:

```
echo "hm={$yes["n"]}";
```

I need to replace every instance of (whitespace) with `+`. What I tried was putting this:

```
str_replace(" ","+",{$yes["n"]});
```

before I echoed it out.

It said unexepected `{`, so I tried:

```
str_replace(" ","+",$yes["n"]);
```

Where nothing happened.

Comment: Try single quotes around your yes variable `hm$={$yes['n']}`

Comment: Please show us more code! ($array declaration, code above)

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to assign the output of str_replace to the variable.

```
$yes["n"] = 'string with whitespace';
$yes["n"] = str_replace(" ","+",$yes["n"]);
echo "hm={$yes["n"]}"; // echoes hm=string+with+whitespace
```